# switch from WebSocket to RawSocket Transport

Tags: autobahn, crossbar

I am new to crossbar/autobahn framework and to network programming in general, recently  at work we would like to experiment to move from WebSocket transport to RawSocket Transport with using MessagePackSerializer and do performance comparison. I am requesting to the framework developers to please guide me to convert following config to use raw socket. will using auth settings from `ws` section should work ?

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "workers": [
    {
      "type": "router",
      "options": {
        "pythonpath": ["../components"]
      },
      "realms": [
        {
          "name": "realm1",
          "roles": [
            {
              "name": "system",
              "authorizer": "com.XXXX.auth.authorize"
            },
            {
              "name": "user",
              "authorizer": "com.XXXX.auth.authorize"
            },
            {
              "name": "service",
              "authorizer": "com.XXXX.auth.authorize"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "transports": [
        {
          "type": "rawsocket",
          "endpoint": {
            "type": "unix",
            "path": "/tmp/crossbar-socket"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "web",
          "endpoint": {
            "type": "tcp",
            "port": 8080
          },
          "paths": {
            "status": {
              "type": "resource",
              "classname": "health_web_indicator.run",
              "extra": {
                "DVMT_VERSION": "2.0.1",
                "HEALTHY_INDICATOR": ":) DVMT UP",
                "UNHEALTHY_INDICATOR": ":( DVMT DOWN",
                "MSSQL_DRIVER": "FreeTDS",
                "MSSQL_SERVER": "XXXX.dv.local",
                "MSSQL_PORT": "1515",
                "MSSQL_DATABASE": "XXXX",
                "MSSQL_USER": "XXXX",
                "MSSQL_PASSWORD": "XXXX",
                "SUPERVISOR_PROCESSES": ["XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX"],
                "SUPERVISOR_SERVER_SOCKET": "/crossbar/supervisord.sock"
              }
            },
            "ws": {
              "type": "websocket",
              "auth": {
                "anonymous": {
                  "type": "dynamic",
                  "authenticator": "com.XXXX.auth.authenticate"
                },
                "ticket": {
                  "type": "dynamic",
                  "authenticator": "com.XXXX.auth.authenticate"
                }
              },
              "debug": true,
              "options": {
                "auto_ping_interval": 0,
                "auto_ping_timeout": 60000,
                "auto_ping_size": 4,
                "compression": {
                  "deflate": {
                    "request_no_context_takeover": false,
                    "request_max_window_bits": 11,
                    "no_context_takeover": false,
                    "max_window_bits": 11,
                    "memory_level": 4
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "components": [
        {
          "id": "auth",
          "type": "class",
          "classname": "auth.AuthComponent",
          "realm": "realm1",
          "role": "trusted",
          "extra": {
            "prefix": "com.XXXX.auth",
            "system_role": "system",
            "anonymous_role": "anonymous",
            "mssql": {
              "driver": "FreeTDS",
              "server": "XXXX.dv.local",
              "port": "1515",
              "database": "XXXX",
              "uid": "XXXX",
              "pwd": "XXXX",
              "autocommit": true
            },
            "heartbeat_rate": 30.0,
            "ldap_api_url": "http://XXXX:80/rssapi/dvmsapi/admin/GetUserLdapGroups/{username}",
            "enforce_cert_match": false,
            "cert_sub_pattern": "[\\s_-]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

also will it be easy enough for you to please give me an example for using autobahnpython as a client for rawsocket transport. https://crossbar.io/docs/RawSocket-Transport/#example---connecting-transport